# Unable to Write Contents of Jar File to Local Servlet on Tomcat 7.0.22

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jar, fileoutputstream

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to extract the contents of a jar file programmatically and found a code snippet  [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22124) which has allowed me to extract the contents of a jar file on my local machine without the use of a servlet.

Now that I know the code works I am trying to use it in a local servlet environment, specifically Tomcat 7.0.22. So far I have the code below but have been unable to output the contents of the jar. I believe that I am not handling the output stream correctly and that is why nothing is saved to the local directory of my local Tomcat server.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction or offer some advice on how to correct the code so that it outputs the contents read to a file?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JarExtractor extends HttpServlet {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {

        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("test.jar");
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(path);
        Enumeration jarEnum = jar.entries();

        while (jarEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry file = (JarEntry) jarEnum.nextElement();
            File f = new File(file.getName());
            if (file.isDirectory()) {       // if its a directory, create it
                f.mkdir();
                continue;
            }
            InputStream in = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
            while (in.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
                output.write(in.read());
            }
            output.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        //------
    }   
}
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
  try 
      {
      doPost(request,response);
  } 
      catch (ServletException e) 
      {
    // 
  } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
    //
  }
}
```

}

Thank you very much for any help anyone is able to provide.

Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: What actually happens? Do you have write access to wherever you're trying to write to? Do you even know where you're writing to?

Comment: Nothing happens, when I was running the code with println's it would print up until I would initialize the output stream and then nothing more. I believe that I have write permissions because I am running Tomcat locally and have a servlet that uploads and saves files that works fine. I am writing to ~/(tomcat-dir)/wtpwebapps/APP-NAME right now. The 'test.jar' file is located in ~/wtpwebapps/APP-NAME

Comment: Your code does not make sense. It seems to me that you try to write all entries found in the JAR file back to its originating location. What exactly do you want to achieve - read an existing JAR and...?

Comment: I would like to read the contents of an existing JAR (test.jar) and write the contents of that jar to disk, basically extracting that jar but keeping the file structure intact. I think that I may have fiddled with it so much that it doesn't make much sense anymore. All I am trying to do is take the already working http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22124 code and use it as a servlet.

Comment: Did you try with the real path for the output file as well?

Comment: Awesome, I modified:

JarFile jar = new JarFile(path+java.io.File.separator+"test.jar");
and
File f = new File(path+java.io.File.separator+file.getName());

So that I was not writing to the same file since I didn't notice that's what I was pretty much doing and it worked. Thank you very much for your help, I knew it was something stupid, but I have been looking at it so much I couldn't see it.

Comment: I'll convert the comment to an answer (easier for searchers to find). Glad you got it working :)

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you. Enjoy your Sunday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output file also needs to be based on the real path (or other known location) otherwise you're probably writing outside of the servlet context to a location based on just the jar component's name.